# Merging two different parent nodes content based on the same child value (ID) - XSL Transform

Tags: xslt

I couldn't find this specific scenario (guess I can`t describe it right in english).

The input XML looks something like this (multiple items inside "listOne" and "listTwo" of course:

```
<root>

   <listOne>

      <listOneItem>
         <ID>1</ID> // Always Unique
         <SKU>ABC</SKU>
      </listOneItem>

   </listOne>

   <listTwo>

      <listTwoItem>
         <ID>1</ID> / Identical to node in listOneItem, but unique (no scenario of a third element with such ID)
         <STOCK>10</STOCK>
      </listTwoItem>

   </listTwo>

</root>
```

The desired output should merge the "listOne" and "listTwo" items based on the same child "ID" nodes value:

```
<root>

   <finalItemsList>

     <item>

       <ID>1</ID>
       <SKU>ABC</SKU>
       <STOCK>10</STOCK>

     </item>

   </finalItemsList>

</root>
```

Comment: That is just another variation of grouping two elements by the value of a child element, see your favourite text book on XSLT on grouping or see whether the examples in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT has a built-in [**key**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#key) mechanism to resolve cross-references:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="list2" match="listTwoItem" use="ID" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <root>
        <finalItemsList>
            <xsl:for-each select="listOne/listOneItem">
                <item>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="key('list2', ID)/STOCK"/>
                </item>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </finalItemsList>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank You! I'm new to this and learning the (powerfull and heplfull for me at the moment) XSL for one specific task would take me a lot of time! It`s not just a copy/paste scenario for me - the "grouping" by "creating the key" will help me a lot!

Comment: @MartinPetro Grouping is a different technique. I don't think you need it here, but it is worthy of learning.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a native speaker, but I understand, "grouping" isn't the right word in English for the solution I was looking for. Cheers from Slovakia! :)

Comment: Just to clarify, you *could* achieve the same result by grouping all items, from both lists, by their common ID. But IMHO using a key is much simpler - esp. in XSLT 1.0. Pozdrav.