# Copy elements values by using "for-each" from one element to another element in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am faced with a challenge to copy values from one element to another element by using 2 distinct "for-each". The XML document that I have looks like that:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DocName>
    <Element1>
        <Element2>
            <Header>
                <Document type="Gift">
                    <DocumentID>
                        <ID>Items</ID>
                    </DocumentID>
                </Document>
            </Header>
            <DetailItem>
                <Document type="Gift">
                    <DocumentID>
                        <ID>Bracelet</ID>
                    </DocumentID>
                    <Line>1</Line>
                </Document>
            </DetailItem>
            <DetailItem>
                <Document type="Gift">
                    <DocumentID>
                        <ID>Necklace</ID>
                    </DocumentID>
                    <Line>2</Line>
                </Document>
            </DetailItem>
            <DetailItem>
                <Document type="Gift">
                    <DocumentID>
                        <ID>Broche</ID>
                    </DocumentID>
                    <Line>3</Line>
                </Document>
            </DetailItem>
            <DetailUnit>
                <DocumentReference>
                    <DocumentID>
                        <ID>DOC1</ID>
                    </DocumentID>
                    <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
                </DocumentReference>
                <!-- Copy the value from Line 1 above -->
                <AddMe>Bracelet</AddMe>
            </DetailUnit>
            <DetailUnit>
                <DocumentReference>
                    <DocumentID>
                        <ID>DOC2</ID>
                    </DocumentID>
                    <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
                </DocumentReference>
                <!-- Copy the value from Line 2 above -->
                <AddMe>Necklace</AddMe>
            </DetailUnit>
            <DetailUnit>
                <DocumentReference>
                    <DocumentID>
                        <ID>DOC3</ID>
                    </DocumentID>
                    <LineNumber>3</LineNumber>
                </DocumentReference>
                <!-- Copy the value from Line 3 above -->
                <AddMe>Broche</AddMe>
            </DetailUnit>
        </Element2>
    </Element1>
</DocName>
```

What I need to do is copy the values from "DetailItem" nodes (i.e. "Bracelet" that belongs to Line 1, "Necklace" that belongs to Line 2 and "Broche" that belongs to Line 3) to a new "AddMe" element in "DetailUnit" that corresponds to the same line number.

Our system creates new records in a Database for "DetailItem" values and then starts updating these records with data captured in "DetailUnit" nodes.

Please note that it's not similar to the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66587310/merging-two-different-parent-nodes-content-based-on-the-same-child-value-id) where the 2 nodes merge, I don't want to merge the nodes.

The problem is that I have very limited knowledge in XSL, therefore I need your help.

Many thanks

Comment: *"I have very limited knowledge in XSL"* That's not an excuse to ask us to write your code for you. Ask a **specific** question about a difficulty you encountered when trying to accomplish this.

Comment: I know to write XSL but not when it comes to run the xml file in 2 different iterations, the first to get the values from a list of nodes and another to update another set of nodes not related to the first one where the only link between both is the "LineNumber". Please reopen the question because the solution provided to merge 2 nodes is NOT the same as the one I want.

Comment: I disagree. The problem of *"update another set of nodes not related to the first one where the only link between both is the "LineNumber""* is **exactly** the problem solved in the answer I linked to. If you're having problems implementing it, edit your question and show (1) an example of the input XML; (2) your attempted XSLT using a *key* to get a value from a related node; and (3) the expected result.

Comment: You were right. It worked the way it's described in the other post. Thanks for your help