# XSLT 1.0, match attribute values and get child elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am very new to this and I have an XML that I want to transform with XSLT (1.0) to a different XML format.

There is a list of chapters, where each chapter has a set of authors. The problem is that the authors are only referenced by an attribute id, the names of the authors are actually under a different node.

This is a shortened example of the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<monograph xmlns="http://pkp.sfu.ca" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <publication>
  <authors>
   <author id="100">
    <givenname>Mange</givenname>
   </author>
   <author id="101">
    <givenname>Jonas</givenname>
   </author>
  </authors>
  <chapters>
 <chapter>
  <title>Title 1</title>
  <chapterAuthor author_id="100"/>
  <chapterAuthor author_id="101"/>
 </chapter>
 <chapter>
  <title>Title 2</title>
  <chapterAuthor author_id="101"/>
 </chapter>
</chapters></publication></monograph>
```

This is the XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:pkp="http://pkp.sfu.ca" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">

          <xsl:for-each select="/pkp:monograph/pkp:publication/pkp:chapters/pkp:chapter">
            <content_item component_type='chapter'>
              <contributors>
                <xsl:for-each select="./pkp:chapterAuthor">
                  <person_name sequence='first' contributor_role='author'>
                    <given_name>
                      <xsl:if test="/pkp:monograph/pkp:publication/pkp:authors/pkp:author[@user_group_ref='Author']/@id = './@author_id'">
                        <xsl:value-of select="/pkp:monograph/pkp:publication/pkp:authors/pkp:author/pkp:givenname"/>
                      </xsl:if>
                    </given_name>
                    <surname>
                    </surname>
                  </person_name>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </contributors>
              <titles>
                <title>
                  <xsl:value-of select="./pkp:title"/>
                </title>
              </titles>
            </content_item>
          </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<content_item component_type="chapter" xmlns:pkp="http://pkp.sfu.ca">
  <contributors>
    <person_name sequence="first" contributor_role="author">
      <given_name />
      <surname />
    </person_name>
    <person_name sequence="first" contributor_role="author">
      <given_name />
      <surname />
    </person_name>
  </contributors>
  <titles>
    <title>Title 1</title>
  </titles>
  <pages>
    <first_page></first_page>
    <last_page></last_page>
  </pages>
</content_item>
<content_item component_type="chapter" xmlns:pkp="http://pkp.sfu.ca">
  <contributors>
    <person_name sequence="first" contributor_role="author">
      <given_name />
      <surname />
    </person_name>
  </contributors>
  <titles>
    <title>Title 2</title>
  </titles>
  <pages>
    <first_page></first_page>
    <last_page></last_page>
  </pages>
</content_item>
```

As you can see it succeeds in creating a `content_item` for each `chapter` in the original XML and getting the corresponding `title`, but I can't figure out how to get the `author`(s).

Long story short, I need to get the XSLT to somehow match the value of the attribute `publication/chapters/chapter/chapterAuthor@author_id` with the value of the attribute `publication/authors/author@id`, then get the value of the corresponding element `author/givenname` to appear in the `contributors/person_name/given_name` element of the output.

In the example I've tried an `if` test to try to get it to find the attributes that equal each other, but as you can see it doesn't work.

Is there a proper way that this could be done? I would be so helpful for any tips, even if it's just a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Use a *key* - here is one of many examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66587595/3016153